# Compare Table Row Count to Previous Table Row Count of Same Table inside a While Loop

Tags: sql, powershell

Trying to understand the basic logic to have a table read a count of SQL table rows - store that value.
The next time the table is read - only do something ( in this case write an event to a MS Log File) if the row count has increased.
Basically - looking for a new row that’s been added to the account to trigger an event.

The while($true) is to make this PowerShell script run indefinitely in the background - so this is using a sleep to check table status intermittently

```
    while($true)
{
### there’s a bunch of code to make the connection and variables set before this: 

$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlCommand
$dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
[void]$DataAdapter.Fill($dataset)
$DataSet.Tables[0].'Table Name'
$sqlConnection.Close()
$sqlConnection.Dispose()


### set the number of rows in table since last count 

$dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count | set-content set.txt

$LastRowCount = Get-Content set.txt #this is where I’m stuck on how to apply this last count
                                    #do I need another loop inside?

if($dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count -gt 0 -and $dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count -gt $LastRowCount) {

     write-Eventlog –LogName HUGs –Source Exciter –EventID 101 -Message "testing 123"
 }
 else{
      Write-Host "NO CHANGE IN RECORD COUNT FROM LAST RUN"

     } 
#TAKE A FIVE MINUTE BREAK
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 

 }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: not sure how to place the $LastCount in the logic to properly store the rowcount from a previous run - so I can do the compare last rowcount to current rowcount?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 variable but Im not familiar with powershell so is just some pseudo code

```
$LastRowCount = Get-Content; // Set the variable before the loop

while($true)
{ 
  $CurrentRowCount = Get-Content; // Get the update count

 If $LastRowCount <> $CurrentRowCount then 
 {
    write-Eventlog –LogName HUGs –Source Exciter –EventID 101 -Message "testing 123"
    $LastRowCount = $CurrentRowCount // Update the variable for the next loop

 } else {
    Write-Host "NO CHANGE IN RECORD COUNT FROM LAST RUN"
 }
```